# Is there a way to set vertical scroll position of the gridview Xtragrid?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm using Xtragrid Suit to make my windows forms grids.
Is there a way to set the vertical and horizontal scroll position of the gridControl or gridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sometime i found a way to do this using `GridView.LeftCoord` to horizontal scroll and `GridView.TopRowIndex`.

The change of this properties raise this events LeftCoordChanged and TopRowChanged.

I found the information at the link below.

[Is there a way to control the vertical scroll position of the gridview?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q502524)

Comment: If you are using or plan to use the new 13.x version, they've just introduced the "pixel scrolling" feature to allow partial rows to be visible. I don't know yet what kind of changes it introduces in vertical scrollbar handling.